# Problems using cron to run a encrypted php file

Tags: encryption, cron

I'm having problems using cron to run a encrypted php file. The file is encrypted using Source Guardian v8.0 and i can run it successfully when i call th script directly from the browser. The frequency is to run every 24 hours and i'm testing by setting this to every 5 minutes so i can test it quickly. The frequency works ok and im getting the emails to the email address i specify in the job.

my emails contain this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.26
Content-type: text/html
```

but the resultant script(which updates a db table) is not running.

My web host (shared hosting) advised i use:

```
php -c /home/myUserName/public_html/path/to/my/daily/repeated/script.php
```

Source Guardian Support suggest full paths and specifying the php.ini path, thus:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/lib/php.ini -f /home/myUserName/public_html/path/to/my/daily/repeated/script.php
```

Previously i was using:

```
php /home/myUserName/public_html/path/to/my/daily/repeated/script.php
```

Nothing seems to run this script!! with/without switches; full paths or not ... 
any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Try manually running the command on the console to check for errors.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured the Source Guardian loader in the php.ini for CLI, only in the php.ini for the webserver.

Comment: @marven - do you mean SSH i dont think ive got access to it  - tried using puTTY from my machine bu my web hosting (shared) is blocking it. Or do you mean something else - im pretty new to cron

Comment: @ Barmar - do i need to get on to my web-host admin to check this then??